# Interface Builder's User Defined Runtime Attributes not accepting floats?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, key-value-coding, kvc

I created an NSView subclass that has a float property and I'd like to set it in Interface Builder. In the User Defined Runtime Attributes section the only suitable Type is Number. But if I want to enter a decimal number (either using . or , as delimiter) it just rounds to the nearest integer. Is this a bug or on purpose? How can I define a float instead of an Integer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a string type and enter your value like this

```
0.7
```

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!!.  Like DrummerB, this was driving me insane.  And the answer is so simple.

Comment: @DrummerB: because it is completely illogic.

Comment: Huh. This actually works. How fantastically ugly, even by the standards I expect of Xcode. Is this madness documented anywhere? How in the world did you discover it, otherwise?

Comment: It is not documented. I found it when drinking.

Comment: @MarkAmery What standards are you talking about? This is completely illogic, just as many other things with XCode. Like Swift code suggestions, for example.